# clean docker volume with no reclaimable space on local volumes

Tags: docker, jenkins, storage, digital-ocean

I am running Jenkins and Docker, and Jenkins periodically stops working due to a lack of space.

Up til now, docker's cleanup command:

```
docker system prune -a
```

cleared up enough space to resolve this error; however, the available space was smaller each time. What I noticed is that

```
docker system df
```

produces the following output:

```
TYPE                TOTAL ACTIVE SIZE     RECLAIMABLE

Images              4     4      882.9MB  79.15MB (8%)

Containers          6     6      16.45kB  0B (0%)

Local Volumes       4     4      31.95GB  0B (0%)

Build Cache                      0B       0B
```

as you can see, Local Volumes is taking up a giant 32 GB, so

1. is this normal?
2. how can I safely reduce the size of Local Volumes?

Thanks

Comment: You can only reclaim volumes unused space, remove your volume partition files and resize it to reclaim.

Comment: Every time?  What happens when it fills it up again?

Comment: Yes, else docker would be deleting random files from your volumes just to decrease the size used, and I dont think anyone want that. You can create a script to remove useless files and do this for you.

Comment: This seems dangerous - 
 
Is there a way to view the files within a volume?

Comment: If you know the files you can delete, this is not dangerous. Do a `docker volume ls` and get the volume you wanna, and a `docker volume inspect {id}` to see more information about it, including where they are located on you host machine.

Comment: Your first comment is very close to what I did; I ended up stopping docker, deleting the volume (without resizing) and restarted docker.  The disk is down to 1gb and I will see if it fills up again.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a temporary solution that does not involve removing or partitioning the volume - the key is to stop the active container before prune:

find the container id:

```
docker ps
```

stop the that (or all) containers:

```
docker container stop <id>
```

then prune:

```
docker system prune -a
```

and then, if you get a get "getsockopt: connection refused" error, I believe you need to recreate the docker registry:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

This cleans out most of the volume, until it fills up again. I would appreciate it if someone could address why it fills up in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is normal, when you run $docker system prune by default it doesn't prune the volumes, you have to add extra option to trigger it:
use:
$ docker system prune --volumes
or 
$docker volume prune

Comment: Thanks,  but docker system prune --volumes and docker volume prune did not reclaim any space

Comment: it worked for me, however reclaimable space for volumes wasn't 0KB for me.